# New to using RStudio with Bigquery - nested table is not recognized

Tags: r, google-bigquery

I have the following which does not run. I receive the error "Invalid table name: `tk.events_*`". This table is nested but the columns I am using are not (1 value per row).

When I replace the query below with a different, unnested table, it runs as expected. Is there some kind of formatting change I can make to address this?

```
project <- "my-project-765" # put your project ID here

sql <- paste("
             #standardSQL

             select 
userID,
cast(datetime(servertimestamp,'America/Vancouver') as date) as loginDate
FROM `tk.events_*`
where _table_suffix between '20170802' and '20180803'
and ( eventType like '%Viewed' or eventType ='LoginSucceeded')
group by userId, loginDate

              ", 
      sep ="")

df <- query_exec(query=sql, project=project, destination_table = "reports.UserLoginTable_copy", write_disposition = "WRITE_APPEND" , max_pages = 1,  useLegacySql = 'f') ## run query and store in dataframe
```

Edit:

Rewrote the above to be legacySQL and it runs pointing out an issue in my formatting.

```
SELECT userID,
       cast(DATE(DATE_ADD(serverTimestamp, -7, 'HOUR')) AS date) AS loginDate
FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE(tk.events_, TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(),-2,'DAY')), TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE()))
WHERE (eventType LIKE '%Viewed'
       OR eventType ='LoginSucceeded')
GROUP BY userId,
         loginDate
```

Comment: Just wondering, what happens if you run the same query but with `tk.events_20170802` as the table? Does it work?

Comment: Still listed as an invalid table name unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess would be that Standard SQL for some reason was not activated.

Try running this command, maybe it works:

```
df <- query_exec(query=sql, project=project, destination_table = "reports.UserLoginTable_copy", write_disposition = "WRITE_APPEND" , max_pages = 1,  use_legacy_sql = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks - it looks like I used "useLegacySql" instead of "use_legacy_sql" and set it to a string ('false') instead of a boolean as per your example.